# What’s the limit of this function as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

[image]

Im trying to find the limit of this function or check if the limit exists as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$. Every line I’ve tried such as $y=x, y=-x, y=x^2$, etc all lead to the limit being $0$ but I’m sure this isn’t right. Can anyone find a line that proves the limit doesn’t exist or prove its equal to $0$?

Answer (score 2):

To find counter example a good idea is to homogeneize the formula with $y=tx$ (note that $t$ is not necessarily a constant, see it like the ratio $t=\frac yx$).

$f(x,y)=\dfrac{tx^2(x^2-t^2x^2+t^2x^4)}{x^4+t^4x^4}=\dfrac{t(1-t^2+t^2x^2)}{1+t^4}$

Since now the denominator $>1$, we want to find a suitable $t$ such that the numerator does not go to $0$ while $y$ still go to $0$.

$N(x,y)=t-t^3+t^3x^2\not\to 0$ a trivial choice is $t=2$.

Indeed $f(x,2x)=\dfrac{8x^2-6}{17}\to -\frac 6{17}\neq 0$

Comment: +1 I like this because it introduces readers to the idea of trying 'many' paths at once. Moreover, any readers could also switch to polar coordinates using $x= r \cos \theta, y= r \sin \theta$ and then simplify to see that the limit depends on $\theta$. Choosing 'nice' $\theta$ one could find lines, i.e. $t$ values where the limits will be different. The two methods are the different approaches to the same end and are useful approaches for the limit 'toolbelt.'

Comment: Yes, this is a general method. Note that in case of a true zero limit, you often get $f(x,y)=\phi(t) x^\alpha\to 0$ showing the $\phi$ is a bounded function of $t$. So it does not serve only for finding counter-examples.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Look at the limit along $x=y^{1/3}, y>0$.

Comment: What motivates that choice of path?  Or do you have to just keep guessing until you find something that works?

Comment: Usually taking $x$ to be a power of $y$ works. But you have keep trying various powers until you get a choice that gives the answer. @RobertShore

Answer (score 0):

Take the path $(x,y)=(-2y,y)$. Then on this path, we have
$$f(x,y)=f(-2y,y)=\frac{(-2y)\cdot y\cdot(4y^2-y^2+4y^4)}{16y^4+y^4}$$
$$=\frac{-6y^2-8y^4}{17y^2}\rightarrow -\frac{6}{17}$$
as $y\rightarrow 0$. We conclude that (combined with your previous work) that the limit does not exist.